# Summing up the values of a variable after a loop has ended

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-server, loops

Hello this is the purpose of my program:

23. Savings Account Balance

Write a program that calculates the balance of a savings account at the end of a three month period. It should ask the user for the starting balance and the annual interest rate. A loop should then iterate once for every month int he period, performing the following steps:

A) Ask the user for the total amount deposited into the account during that month and add it to the 
     balance. Do not accept negative numbers.

B) Ask the user for the total amount withdrawn from the account during that month and subtract it 
     from the balance. Do not accept the negative numbers or numbers greater than the balance after
     the deposits for the month have been added in.

C) Calculate the interest for that month. The monthly interest rate is the annual interest rate 
     divided by 12. Multiply the monthly interest rate by the average of that month's starting
     and ending balance to get the interest amount for the month. This amount should be added
     to the balance.

After the last iteration, the program should display a report that includes the following 
  information:

- Starting balance at the beginning of the three-month period
- total deposits made during the three months
- total withdrawals made during the three months
- total interest posted to the account during the three months
- final balance

---

The problem I am having is that at the end when I display the table my total deposits, withdrawals as well as interest amount are only displaying the last instances at the end of the loop and not the total sum over the three months. Here is my code, sorry if its needlessly complex or messy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//variables
double depositAmount;
double withdrawAmount;
int monthPeriod = 3;
double startBalance;
double finalBalance;
double totalBalance;
double annInterestRate;
double monthInterestRate;
double monthInterestAmount;
double monthAverageBalance;
double monthAverageAmount;
int count;

cout << "What is your starting balance?   ";
cin >> totalBalance;
cout << "What is your annual rate?  "; 
cin >> annInterestRate;

for (count = 1; count <= monthPeriod; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter total amount deposited for the month  ";
    cin >> depositAmount;
    while (depositAmount < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error, no negative amounts, please try again." << endl;
        cin >> depositAmount;
    }
    cout << "Enter total amount withdrawn for the month  ";
    cin >> withdrawAmount;
    while (withdrawAmount < 0 || withdrawAmount > totalBalance)
    {
        cout << "Error, no negative amounts or withdrawals greater than your balance. Please try    again" << endl;
        cin >> withdrawAmount;
    }
    startBalance = totalBalance + depositAmount;
    finalBalance = totalBalance - withdrawAmount;
    totalBalance = startBalance - finalBalance;
    monthInterestRate = annInterestRate * 12;
    monthAverageBalance = (startBalance + finalBalance) / 2;
    monthInterestAmount = monthAverageBalance * monthInterestRate;
    totalBalance = monthInterestAmount + totalBalance;
}
cout << "Your starting balance at the beginning of three months " << startBalance << endl;
cout << "Total deposits over three months  " << depositAmount << endl;
cout << "Total withdrawals over three months  " << withdrawAmount << endl;
cout << "Total interest posted to account over three months " << monthInterestAmount << endl;
cout << "Final Balance: " << totalBalance << endl;
cout << "Thank you for using the program!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rethink the way you're using your variables (by name). For instance, shouldn't `cout << "What is your starting balance?   ";
cin >> totalBalance;` be set to read into **startBalance** instead? Write down on paper how you would do this. The first line you write down would be `startBalance`, right? Then how would you handle a deposit (+) or a withdrawal (-) related to that starting balance?

Comment: You're right, I'll change that. My logic though was at the beginning I have a starting balance and then I add or subtract the deposits/withdrawals. So therefore, totalBalance.

Comment: No, `totalBalance` would be what you have at the end, when you produce the final results of `startBalance + deposits - withdrawals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a HW problem, so maybe I'll just give a hint.  Hint: what variable is accumulating the monthly deposits?

Also, an unsolicited answer: your monthly interest rate is probably not 12*Annual rate, it is probably Annual rate / 12.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking that I would maybe need a variable for accumulating the monthly sums, I just don't get how I would code it to gather the three different amounts.

Comment: The += is your friend.  Something like Total_Deposit += depositAmount (which is equivalent to saying Total_Deposit = Total_Deposit + depositAmount).  When I first started coding this use of = drove me mad because mathematically, the two sides are not equal.  It's an assignment statement: make the new value of Total_Deposit equal to the old value of Total_Deposit + depositAmount.

Comment: OH! I had totally forgotten about +=, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!